# In android Background service unable to cal the another function in onStrart

Tags: android, background, android-service

Hai i treid to access the latitude and longtitude value in background service in android Application .But am getting force close(),without calling latitude and longtitude my backgroud service is working fine.but whenever calling the function latitude and longtitude am getting force close.

```
public class MyService extends Service  {
private TextView latituteField;
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 60000; 
SoapObject request=null;

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
private static final String HostUrl ="xxxxx";
//private static final String HostUrl ="  yyyy;
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String methodname="were";

private HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(HostUrl);
    private static TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
       String tag="TestService";
     private Intent MyServiceIntent;
     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
   Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
   }

  @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
   super.onStart(intent, startId);  
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   result();//my problem is here 
  }
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return null;
  }
  private class loca extends Activity implements LocationListener {


@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        float lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
        float lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));

    } else {
        latituteField.setText("provider not available");
        longitudeField.setText("provider not available");
    }
    }
  @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   result();
   }


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
    }
private void result() {
    SoapPrimitive response=null;
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,methodname);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    request.addProperty("Longitude",longitudeField.getText().toString()); 
    request.addProperty("Latitude",latituteField.getText().toString()); 
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     String result = null;
    try
     {          
        httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE+"IService/"+methodname, envelope);
        response = ( SoapPrimitive )envelope.getResponse();
        result=response.toString();
     }
    catch(Exception e)
     {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Exception"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Upload Picture Error:",e.getMessage());
     }

        }
   }
```

**logcat Error**

```
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MyService@44f432b8 with Intent { cmp=com.javaorigin.android.sample.service/.MyService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MyService.result(MyService.java:141)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MyService.onStart(MyService.java:59)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
  01-12 12:52:49.769: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: uuuh force close? where is the Locat error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the variables longitudeField and latituteField from service. These are initialized in activity oncreate which will not be called unless you start the activity.
Further you have defined activity as private. So you wont be able to add this inside Manifest. So you wont be able to launch the activity AFAIK.

**Edit**: You will have to change the design. Move activity outside service class and use Intents to pass information to activity

Comment: if i pass intent its also getting force close

Comment: Above design will never work. Change the design then post another question with your problem.

Comment: InformationIntent = new Intent(this, loca.class);  startActivity(InformationIntent); am trying like this

Comment: As I said, move the Activity class to a separate file, add that activity to Manifest then use Intents